# Select all elements by class in one div

Tags: jquery, dom

Hello all good people.

I need your advice once again (i wait for day when i could say i can solve my programming problems by myself).
I need to write a simple quiz with JavaScript or jQuery. I have done simple questions like ABCD but still i cant crack fill gap questions. Here's my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="../css/nexto.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pytanie">
      <p class="tresc">1. Ile ksiezyców ma ziemia?</p>
      <p class="odpowiedz poprawna">A) 1</p>
      <p class="odpowiedz">A) 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pytanie">
      <p class="tresc">1. Ile ksiezyców ma ziemia?</p>
      <p class="odpowiedz poprawna">A) 1</p>
      <p class="odpowiedz">A) 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pytanie">
      <p class="tresc">Excuse me, how <span contenteditable="true" class="luka-odpowiedz"></span> I get to the nearest underground station?</p>
      <p class="luka-prawidlowa">can </p>
    </div>
    <span class="btn-sprawdz" id="btn-sprawdz-1">Sprawdz</span>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var score;
        score=0;
        // Mechanizm zaznaczania odpowiedzi wielokrotnego wyboru
        $('.odpowiedz').click(function() {
          // Najpierw zdejmij kolor
          $(this).closest('.pytanie').find('p').css('background-color','transparent');
          // Zdejmij selecta
          $(this).closest('.pytanie').find('p').removeClass('selected');
          // Zaznacz tę odpowiedź
          $(this).css('background-color','blue');
          // Oznacz ją jako zaznaczoną
          $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Mechanizm sprawdzania odpowiedzi wielokrotnego wyboru
        $('#btn-sprawdz-1').click(function() {
          // Iteruje po odpowiedziach i pobieram class
          $('.odpowiedz').each(function() {
            var wartosc_odpowiedzi = $(this).attr('class');
            // Jeśli selected i poprawna + punkt
            if (wartosc_odpowiedzi == "odpowiedz poprawna selected") {
              score++;
            }
          });
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Mechanizm sprawdzania luk
        $('.luka-odpowiedz').each(function() {
          // Pobieramy odpowiedź użytkownika
          var wartosc_odpowiedzi = $(this).text();
          var wzorzec_odpowiedzi = $(this).closest('.luka-prawidlowa').text;
          alert(wzorzec_odpowiedzi);
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8KC7/1/) project.

Gap can have multiple answers (all wits class `.luka-prawidlowa` i tried to take all paragraps in loop, and compare user answer to `.luka-prawidlowa` But i get some trash instead. Anyone can help me?

------- EDIT --------
Answer of @Spokey works great - in meantime i do it other way. Diffrence was in `.each` loop. before it was

```
$('.luka-odpowiedz').each(function() {
              // Pobieramy odpowiedź użytkownika
              var wartosc_odpowiedzi = $(this).text();
              var wzorzec_odpowiedzi = $(this).closest('.luka-prawidlowa').text;
              alert(wzorzec_odpowiedzi);
              });
```

but I go one step up to `.pytanie` and do it like:

```
$('.pytanie-luka').each(function() {
          // Pobieramy odpowiedź użytkownika
          var wartosc_odpowiedzi = $(this).find('.luka-odpowiedz').text();
          var wzorzec_odpowiedzi = $(this).find('.luka-prawidlowa').text();

          });
```

I must change `.pytanie` to `.pytanie-luka` for loop iterate only with fill a gap questions. But still @Spokey approach seems better one.

Comment: i didn't see `.luka-odpowiedz` in you fiddle... are u missing some elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
  $('#btn-sprawdz-1').click(function () {
        // Iteruje po odpowiedziach i pobieram class
        $('.odpowiedz').each(function () {
            var wartosc_odpowiedzi = $(this).attr('class');
            // Jeśli selected i poprawna + punkt
            if (wartosc_odpowiedzi == "odpowiedz poprawna selected") {
                score++;
            }
        });
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Mechanizm sprawdzania luk
        var fill = $('.luka-odpowiedz').text(); // save span text on click 

        $('.luka-prawidlowa').each(function () { 
          // for each paragraph 
          //your mistake here was to use for each span instead of paragraph

            if (fill === $(this).text()) { // if span text is like paragraph
                alert('ok');  // do something
            }
        });
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8KC7/5/)

---

---

**New script (I did not see that you are using the same class everywhere).**

I suggest that you add another class to `.pytanie` (in my example `.gap-fill`). 
It's not necessary to add a new class, but it is better for performance. (each won't have to browse every div that is not a gap filling question)

```
$('.gap-fill').each(function () {
      var th = $(this);
      var text = th.find('.luka-odpowiedz').text();

      th.find('.luka-prawidlowa').each(function(){
          if(text === $(this).text()){ score++; }
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8KC7/9/

NOTE: I also reseted score when you click the button.

Comment: One more time thanks for help but your solution have a little glitch. When I add one more question script dosnt work correctly. When I fill correctly both gaps it count me 0 points - if I fill only one gap it count point :( Any idea?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using `.luka-odpowiedz` for your `span` class and `.luka-prawidlowa` for your answer class. **Each question should have it's own classes**. The function is now probably checking the wrong span with the wrong answer. Can you show a new fiddle with your new questions?